# Prevent NSButtonCell image from drawing outside of its containing NSScrollView

Tags: cocoa, core-graphics, nsimage, nsscrollview, nsbuttoncell

I have [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099881/image-inside-nsscrollview-drawing-on-top-of-other-views) (and answered) a very similar question before.  That question was able to be solved because I knew the `dirtyRect`, and thus, knew where I should draw the image. Now, I am seeing the same behavior with an subclassed `NSButtonCell`:

[image]

In my subclass, I am simply overriding the `drawImage:withFrame:inView` method to add a shadow.

```
- (void)drawImage:(NSImage *)image withFrame:(NSRect)frame inView:(NSView *)controlView {   

    NSGraphicsContext *ctx = [NSGraphicsContext currentContext];
    [ctx saveGraphicsState];

    // Rounded Rect
    NSBezierPath *path = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:frame cornerRadius:kDefaultCornerRadius];
    NSBezierPath *shadowPath = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:NSInsetRect(frame, 0.5, 0.5) cornerRadius:kDefaultCornerRadius]; // prevents the baground showing through the image corner

    // Shadow
    NSColor *shadowColor = [UAColor colorWithCalibratedWhite:0 alpha:0.8];
    [NSShadow setShadowWithColor:shadowColor
                  blurRadius:3.0
                      offset:NSMakeSize(0, -1)];
    [[NSColor colorWithCalibratedWhite:0.635 alpha:1.0] set];
    [shadowPath fill];
    [NSShadow clearShadow];

    // Background Gradient in case image is nil
    NSGradient *gradient = [[NSGradient alloc] initWithStartingColor:[UAColor grayColor] endingColor:[UAColor lightGrayColor]];
    [gradient drawInBezierPath:shadowPath angle:90.0];
    [gradient release];

    // Image
    if (image) {
        [path setClip];
        [image drawInRect:frame fromRect:CGRectZero operation:NSCompositeSourceAtop fraction:1.0];
    }

    [ctx restoreGraphicsState];
```

}

It seems all pretty standard, but the image is still drawing outside of the containing scrollview bounds. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't call `-setClip` on an `NSBezierPath` unless you *really* mean it. Generally you want `‑addClip`, which adds your clipping path to the set of current clipping regions.

`NSScrollView` works by using its own clipping path and you're blowing that path away before drawing your image.

This tripped me up for a long time too.